# CSV import to content type

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, entities

While  migrating from csv file to content type in Drupal 8 , fields like Geolocation and Address are of type field collections, so for mapping those fields am using migrate source csv  and migrate plus modules in Drupal 8.

is there any other method  to do without any mapping ?

Comment: Is there any other way? Well, you simply could write your own plugin taking https://github.com/GiantRobot/csvimport as an example.

Comment: Do you actually mean "CSV import to node" or even "CSV import to node with field collection"?

Answer (score 0):

Use this module for migrating from csv.

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv

Comment: Already  i mentioned  like i was  using that module....using that migrate source csv  we need to map  geolocation  and address fields  in custom yml to paste and import .....am asking some other way to handle